# Setting proportional column width with <col width="x*" />

Tags: html, html-table, width

I am trying to set proportional column width with `<col width="x*" />`:

```
<table width="600px">
    <col width="1*" />
    <col width="2*" />
    <col width="3*" />
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="border: 1px solid black;">AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA
            </td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid black;">BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB
            </td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid black;">CCC CCC CCC CCC CCC CCC CCC CCC CCC CCC CCC CCC CCC CCC CCC CCC CCC CCC CCC CCC CCC CCC CCC CCC CCC CCC CCC CCC CCC CCC CCC CCC
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Despite setting proportions in `<col>` tag, column widths are equal. What do I do wrong?

Comment: There appears to be a test case for this at http://www.mozilla.org/newlayout/testcases/layout/columnconstraints.html, and it doesn't work for me in Chrome 3.0, Firefox 3.0 or IE 8.0.

Comment: @Dominic Rodger: That doesn't help much:)) `table-layout:fixed` seems to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use 17%, 34%, and 49%. for 1:2:3

Comment: Thanks. I could, but proportional layout is easier to use and since it is part of standard, it would be good to know how to do it.

Comment: If one of the columns you have is fixed width then you can't convert the proportional columns to percentages (unless you know the total width of the table before hand).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get this to work in all the major browsers but have also failed. Google brings up very little except the official spec.

I conclude that proportional column width simply isn't supported by any of the browser makers.  Very odd, since it would seem very useful compared to some of the more esoteric stuff that is supported nowadays.

Comment: At least Microsoft does say IE doesn't support relative widths, although it's not very clear what versions it's talking about: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406073(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use `colgroup`.

From [WSSchools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_colgroup.asp)

> The  tag specifies a group of one or more columns in a table
>   for formatting.
>
> The  tag is useful for applying styles to entire columns,
>   instead of repeating the styles for each cell, for each row.

```css
table {
   width: 100%;
}
td {
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
    <table>
        <colgroup>
            <col span="1" style="width: 15%;">
            <col span="1" style="width: 15%;">
            <col span="1" style="width: 70%;">
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="col_3">On stop credit</th>
                <th class="col_3">Rating</th>
                <th class="col_3">Customer Notes</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Value</td>
                <td>Value</td>
                <td>Long text value</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```